# Set UK date format for SQL Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

How do I permanently set the date format for SQL Express to be UK format (dd/mm/yyyy).

I know I can use `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`, but this only works for that connection.

I have also seen,

```
exec sp_addlanguage 'British', 'English', 'January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October, November,December', 
'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec', 'Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday'
,dmy,1

sp_configure 'default language', 1
```

reconfigure with override

but, this doesn't seem to work with SQL Express (I get, Could not find stored procedure 'sp_addlanguage'.).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [language](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191448.aspx) using [sp_configure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx)

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', '23' -- british_english ?
GO
RECONFIGURE;
```

Edit: need to use code from sys.syslanguages as mentioned

However, default langauge will also [need changed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) for all logins. Hence [@@langage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177557.aspx) showing us_english.

Comment: I get the following error when running that:

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_configure, Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to int.

Comment: I tried replacing 'british' with 23, and that does not error:

However, running SELECT @@language, @@langid still returns us_english, 0