# SQL Query - Change my long date format to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have been researching a lot of similar questions on how to convert date format to DD-MM-YYYY but none work for the date format I'm using.

This is the date format I'm working with:
Wednesday, October 14, 2015 5:57 PM

And this IS a "date" field not a text field.  I have a feeling that the inclusion of the day of the week is precluding my other attempts from working.

I'm new to SQL so forgive me if I'm overlooking something obvious.

Thank you!

Comment: Which [tag:rdbms] are you using? MySQL or MS SQL Server 2005? The question is tagged with both.

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? Dates in databases (be it MySQL or SQL Server) don't have a format, they just display differently, usually because of a regional setting/culture.

Comment: You really should just convert the date to a string for presentation (using `convert()`.  But, if you want to change the default display format, read the documentation.  Here is a good place to start:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/173907.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I'm writing my query specifically for relating tables in ExactTarget, and it prefers SQL Server 2005 but I've noticed it accepts mySql in a lot of cases as well (hence both tags).

Comment: By "format" I mean that's how the data displays in the table I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, there are generally four ways to control date formatting.

1. Control it in your application.  Most queries to the database return result sets that are typed.  So a `datetime` column will be of data type datetime or timestamp in your application.  You then apply the formatting from your application.  The drawback to this is that, well, you wouldn't be asking this question if this were your problem.
2. Use [the `CONVERT()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), which allows limited formatting of datetime, datetime2, date, and time fields.  `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)` will format the column to `dd/mm/yyyy`.  The drawback to this is that you have to do it for every field you want to format every time you want to format them, and you lose the data typing since you're actually converting them to strings.
3. Use the [`SET DATEFORMAT` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) or the [`SET LANGUAGE` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) prior to executing your query.  You can execute `SET DATEFORMAT dmy; SELECT GETDATE()` and your dates will be in dmy format.  The drawback here is that you have to run it every time you run a query.  Also note that since this returns your columns with data type intact, it's possible that your query analyzer will reformat the dates on you.
4. If you want to *permanently* set the date format, then ultimately you need to change the language away from us_english (or whatever the default was that was specified when you installed the server).  You can see the list of available language configurations by running [`exec sp_helplanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187357.aspx), and you can see the currently configured language for your session by running `SELECT @@LANGUAGE`.  I know it's possible to [set up your own languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849224/set-uk-date-format-for-sql-express) if you need to, but be aware that's a custom configuration you'd have to deploy if you're running that kind of application.

Language configuration is potentially very complicated, since it's determined by the user, login, database or server, depending on where exactly it's specified.  As far as I'm aware, logins inherit the server's default language, and users inherit the database's default language.  User language is usually not specifed, but I believe it overrides the login language when present.  I've only ever run in configurations where everything was defaulted to us_english, so I've not had much experience with this set up.  You can modify it with `ALTER LOGIN` or `ALTER USER`, and you can set the [default language on the server with `sp_configure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190682.aspx) and on the database with `ALTER DATABASE`.